# Inserting data into a database via Tkinter entries

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I want to have a tkinter gui that has an entry widget along with a button that a user can enter a number into the entry field then click the "submit" button. When the button is pressed I want his entry to store to a database I have set up.

my code so far is as follows:

```
db = Mysqldb.connect('localhost', 'root', '----', '----', 'design')

cursor = db.cursor()

def submit_it():
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO time VALUES (data.get())')

data = Entry(gui2,  text = 'food name')

data.place(x=100,y=100)

submit = Button(gui2, text = 'submit', command = submit_it())

submit.place(x=200,y=200)
```

any ideas on how I could get this to work would be greatly appreciated... again, all I am wanting to do is have the user input something into the entry field and click the submit button. when this is done his entry will get saved into my database :)

Answer (score 1):

Two things you will need to change, place data.get() as a parameter and not directly in the operation. And don't call submit_it when passing it as a command for the button.

```
db = Mysqldb.connect('localhost', 'root', '----', '----', 'design')
cursor = db.cursor()

def submit_it():
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO time VALUES (%s)', (data.get(),)) # place data.get() as a parameter as a type or list 

data = Entry(gui2,  text = 'food name')
data.place(x=100,y=100)

submit = Button(gui2, text = 'submit', command = submit_it) # don't call submit_it, get rid of the ()
submit.place(x=200,y=200)
```

You probably also want to commit and close the database later using `db.commit()` and `db.close()` to save the changes.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but I am getting an error that says the following:                    OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")         any ideas?

Comment: @python_beginner_coder How many columns do you have in `time`? And what is an example input?

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.7 you should not call the `submit_it()` function, instead keep it as `submit_it`.
For passing user input use %s instead of directly using data.get().

```
db = Mysqldb.connect('localhost', 'root', '----', '----', 'design')

cursor = db.cursor()

user_input = data.get()

def submit_it():
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO time VALUES (%s)', user_input)

data = Entry(gui2,  text = 'food name')

data.place(x=100,y=100)

submit = Button(gui2, text = 'submit', command = submit_it)

submit.place(x=200,y=200)
```

For inserting multiple values at a time, pass list or tuple of variables that has user input values in it.

Multiple value insert example:

```
# suppose you have 3 inputs as name, quantity, color
# then use...
Name = name.get()
Quantity = quantity.get()
Color = color.get() 
def submit_it():
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO time(name, quantity, color)VALUES (%s, %s, %s)', (Name, Quantity, Color))
```

Also, to successfully add the values to the database, u should `db.commit()` and `db.close()`